# MATLAB editor shortcut 'paste without formatting'?

Tags: matlab

Is there a possibility to define a shortcut for 'paste without formatting' in the MATLAB editor? I want for example to paste text without indentation. In LibreOffice this can be done using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

I've looked in Preferences/MATLAB/Keyboard/Shortcuts and I couldn't find it in the list of shortcuts - or I've overlooked it. I use 'Windows Default Set', but I think this has no influence on the list. If it does not exist, is there a possibility to tweak the editor (e.g. by using some undocumented feature)?

Comment: Why do you want to drop the indentation?

Comment: Maybe the way to go is with macros: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/editormacro-v2-setting-command-window-key-bindings

Comment: @Yvonit it saves time being able to paste something in place

Comment: You can select pasted text and press `CTRL`+`[` several times to drop the indentation.